# How do I catch empty textbox without conflicting my sql?

Tags: php

I have a SQL query to get my id and insert a new id into the database. How am I supposed to alert the user if he has not entered in anything in the textbox before submitting? What should I add?

Here is my code:

```
if ($_GET['username'])
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$_GET[username]'");
    if ($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user['user_name'];
    }
    else
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `personality_test`.`users` (`user_name`)VALUES ('$_GET[username]');");
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = mysql_insert_id();
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_GET['username'];
    }
}

if ($_SESSION['user_id'])
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $user_result = json_decode($row['user_result'], true);

    if (!empty($user_result))
    {
        header('Location:result.php');
    }
        else
        {
            header('Location:index.php');
        }
}
```

Comment: First you learn about and fix your [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities. Then you should realize that this has nothing do with sql. if the user hasn't filled out a form properly, you shouldn't even GET to the sql stage. `if (form not filled out properly) { show error }`.

Comment: Which textbox? You shouldn't use mysql_* as it's deprecated, if you for some reason must then at least escape properly.

Comment: i have to include if to catch the empty textbox and the post earlier to be executed in else statement?

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
 if ($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Needs to be

```
 if ($user == mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

And I would use Javascript to make sure the textbox isn't empty before letting them submit.

Comment: And as Mark said, learn how to prevent SQL injection.  If you are new to PHP, now is the time to learn.  I personally like PDO.

Comment: Also after looking at your code more...  While what I said above is relevant (the = needs to be == when comparing in if statements), it's not the only issue you have here...  If I get more time, I'll try to help point you in the right direction.